# How to write inner join for Rails Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want  Rails Active Record query for the in case of below sql query

Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT parent_id FROM categories INNER JOIN categories_coaches ON categories.id = categories_coaches.category_id
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also its not Ruby query, its Rails Active Record query.

Comment: @pavan thanks for correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Category.select(:parent_id).joins(:category_coaches)`

Comment: i edited the query like this with 2 queries . i don't know to write the rails active record for this `SELECT c.name FROM categories as c where c.id IN (select c.parent_id FROM categories as c join categories_coaches as cc on c.id=cc.category_id where cc.coach_id=17 group by c.parent_id)`